# Converting tuple seq<string * seq<string>>

Tags: f#, tuples

I have to turn my variable `seq<string * seq<string>>` into a `seq<string * string>`.

I have the following data

```
[
    ("hello", ["1";"2";"3";"4"]);
    ("hello2", ["2";"5";"3";"9"]);
    ("hello3", ["1";"12";"35";"46"])
]
```

What I need is:

```
[
    ("hello", "1");
    ("hello", "2");
    ("hello", "3");
    ("hello", "4");
    ("hello2", "2");
    ("hello2", "5");
    ("hello2", "3");
    ("hello2", "9");
    ("hello3", "1");
    ("hello3", "12");
    ("hello3", "35");
    ("hello3", "46")
]
```

Is it feasible with a single function?

Comment: Thanks for the downvote....you are for sure one of those who has been born "expert developer"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`Seq.collect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee340468.aspx):

```
yourList
|> Seq.collect (fun (s, subList) ->     
    subList |> Seq.map(fun (str) -> (s, str))
)
```

As a side note, you used the word "unboxing" wrongly in your question. In .net, boxing and unboxing have [another meaning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)

Comment: I've seen. A user suggested an edit. 
Very nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to `Seq.collect` is to use list expressions:

```
[ for first, subElements in yourList do
    for second in subElements do
      yield first, second ]
```

Comment: What do you mean by LINQ?

Comment: I'm guessing by LINQ it's Collection Pipelines.